# How to define a main database schema in symfony?

Tags: php, database, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

The main intention is to use several project instances on one database which has access to their own schema (instance1, instance2 etc...) 
And a global schema for general information (users, user groups, user teams). Global schema is set through annotations

```
@ORM\Table(name="global.user")
```

Instance schemas tables has foreign keys to global schema tables.

I made a kernel event listener which changes entities metadata:

```
    $this->em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $metadataFactory = $this->em->getMetadataFactory();
    $allEntitiesMetadata = $metadataFactory->getAllMetadata();

    foreach ($allEntitiesMetadata as $entityMetadata) {
        $entityMetadata = $metadataFactory->getMetadataFor($entityMetadata->getName());
        // global entities has global schema defined here
        if (!array_key_exists('schema', $entityMetadata->table)) {
            $entityMetadata->table['schema'] = 'instance1';
        }
    }
```

And maybe there is an easier way to define a default schema for symfony project?

Comment: What are you trying to do with your database? Be more specific.

Comment: I need to share same information among several project instances. For example every company department (instance) has to access employee information (global). Each instance has its own unique information (invoices, products etc...)

Comment: I suggest to use two different entity managers within youre project: 1st is available for anyone and just connection to the 'global' scheme, 2nd entity manager is custom and accesses always you're project specific instance.